# How to get (print) the index of an element with respect to its parent

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am generating `div` inside a `div` by clicking on Add more button and I want to get the index of the generated element so that I can print the name of the `div` like "div-1", "div-2", ...."div-n" and when I remove the `div` the next of that should take the place of that `div`.

my code is

```
  <div id="dataTable" class="master_table ">
  </div>    

<input type="button" value="Add More" class="addmore"/>
<input type="hidden" id="rowCounter" value="0"/>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/um62h/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function for adding/removing:

```
$(".master_table div").each(function(index){
    $(this).attr("name", "div_" + index)
});
```

**EDIT**

Change your js code to this:

```
$('.addmore').on('click', function() {
  $("#dataTable").append('<div class="wd_foutyeight_new"><span></span>'+
  '<br><label>Name</label><input type="text" name="textbox11[]" value=""/>'+
  '<label>Relation  </label><input type="text" name="textbox1[]" value=""/>'+
  '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove_btn">Remove</a></div>');
  renumber();
});

$('#dataTable').on("click", ".remove_btn", function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
  renumber();
});

function renumber() 
{
  $('#dataTable div span').each(function(index){
    $(this).text("Contact Detail " + (index + 1));
  });    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. please visit my given jsfiddle link and clik on add more button. after genrating 5-6 contact detail remove any one of them the you can understand what i am looking for...Thanks in advance

Comment: Alternative is $(this).index()+1

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$('#dataTable > div').each(function(index){
   console.log("div-"+ index); // div-0,div-1
});
```

Comment: since `.each(index)` you can make use of it instead of counting.